# React function as props passed showing is not a function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, react-hooks, react-props

[Parent Component Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9VwcR.png)

**Image shows the parent class passing function and object as props**

```
Export const CaseCard = ({
    image, title, industry, geography, link, showModal, getFormId,
}) => {
    const handleClick = () => {
        showModal();
    };

    return (
```

When running the code it shows error i.e., **showModal(); is not a function**.
I think I'm doing destructuring the wrong way.
Any suggestions???

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
export const CaseCard = (props) => {
    const handleClick = () => {
        props.showModal();
    };
}
```

If you want to explicitly define which props should be passed, see the [Typechecking With PropTypes](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html) guide or use TypeScript.

Comment: The op just destructured the props. You are doing same as op instead you didnot destruct the props

Answer (score 0):

The approach was right, but I was placing modal inside Card Component. The solution is to place modal in the near parent component of Card.